# Two input types - Initializer list (C++)

Tags: c++

I need the instance `str` is able to accept two diferent types. I have to use notation with `{}`. It should be `std::initializer_list`.

```
const UTF8String str{ };
```

This works:

```
class UTF8String {

public:
    std::string inputString;
};

int main() {    
    
    const UTF8String str{ "hello" };

    return 0;
}
```

This works:

```
class UTF8String {

public:
    int inputInt;
};

int main() {    
    const UTF8String str{ 5 };

    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
class UTF8String {

public:
    std::string inputString;
    int inputInt;
};

int main() {    
    
    const UTF8String str{ "hello" };
    const UTF8String str{ 5 };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the following meets yours needs, but it seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>

class UTF8String
{
   public:
      std::string inputString;
      int inputInt;
      UTF8String(const char s[]) : inputString(s) {}
      UTF8String(int i) : inputInt(i) {}
};

int main()
{
   const UTF8String str1{ "hello" };
   const UTF8String str2{ 5 };

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Choosing a different constructor signature for the string version may make it more efficiently reuseable in some scenarios: `UTF8String(std::string&& str) noexcept : inputString(std::move(str)) { }`